# Switch with 2 red, 2 black and 1 ground wire

Tags: multiway-switch

I have a switch indoors which controls two outdoor daylights. I opened the wall plate and found that it has two red wires and two black wires and one ground (so 5 terminals in all). I stuck a multimeter on them and only one of the black ones has voltage, the rest are all 0.

Now, I want to replace this whole thing with a timer switch, which has one line, one load and one neutral. I've taken care of the neutral (together with all the other neutrals in the box), but I am a bit confused about what to put in the line and load.

How can I make my timer switch control both the daylight bulbs? Also, what kind of a switch is that, which has five terminals?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post a picture?

Comment: Unfortunately I removed all the wires from the switch. But it was a switch with 2 terminals on each side + 1 ground. There were 2 red and 2 black wires connected to the 4 terminals. The switch looks like this: - https://goo.gl/ozPRqS

Comment: Are there other switches that control these same lights?  Specifically at least 2 more?  Sounds like a 4-way, only think that doesn’t make sense is 2 terminals should be hot.

Comment: Or a double pole, still doesn’t explain one hot tho.

Comment: @Tyson - I haven't been able to find any other switches that control the same lights. The one switch controls 2 lights though, does that change things?

Comment: @Tyson - why does a double pole need 2 hot wires? Could it be wired in series?

Comment: Did you measure the voltage after removing the wires or before? I could see this having a single hot feeding it, an unswitched hot going elsewhere, and two switched hots for multiple lights. It would explain everything. Also, what on earth do you mean about series wiring a double-pole? A double-pole switch is *inherently* a parallel device.

Comment: Good point @HariGanti

Comment: However I have seen double pole switches used in weird ways, like the 2nd side not being 120v

Comment: @Tyson Sure, you can do unusual things I suppose, but putting a 2-pole in series would just short...

Comment: @HariGanti I never said series... OP did.  But for example I’ve seen pole 2 used as 24v not 120v.  Hard to say until OP posts a picture and/or answers your question about testing with wires connected or removed.

Comment: @Tyson I know you didn't say anything about putting them in series, but I don't understand the OP's comment in the context of series vs parallel because of this.

Comment: If you wire up one of the red wires to the hot black with a wirenut and turn the power back on, does one of the lights turn on?

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to explain what was going on. 

You're right that I measured the voltage after removing all the wires. 

So now I connected the timer switch across the hot wire and one particular other red wire, and now both lights are working. I just capped off the other wires.

pics are here: https://imgur.com/a/qEIzgZa

This pic is older though, noy my current setup, but it shows the two black wires and two red wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the line to the one hot wire.  The black wire in its cable gets capped off. Connect the load to the black or red wire of the other cable, you'll know you have the right one because the light will work.  Cap off the other one.

This combination will work until you find one of the other 3-way or 4-way switches in the system.  Then, it will fail until you throw that switch back.  Your layout is

```
  ---- 3way ==== 4way ==== 3way ----
  ----------------------------------
```

or

```
  ---- 3way ==== 4way ==== 4way ==== 4way ==== 3way -----
  -------------------------------------------------------
```

with any number of 4ways in the middle.

I have a personal rule that "the last guy" probably had a pretty good reason for doing it that way.  So before you take a wrecking ball to his work, look for those reasons.  Otherwise later, you'll be going "Gosh, it'd be a lot more convenient if it worked like --- oh right, it *already did* and I destroyed it  because I didn't understand it".  Those 4-way switches are about $10 each, people don't use those without a pretty good reason.

Comment: Thanks!. I did something like this and I think it worked. I connected the line to the hot wire (black) and I connected the load to one of the red wires and now both lights work. I actually tried connecting the load to all three of the other wires one by one, and only that particular red one worked.

No wrecking ball, I've neatly capped off the other wires. Can restore it if I ever figure out what was going on there.